# Vuex получить обновленные данные

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Есть хранилище

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        profile: null,
    },
    getters: {
        getProfileGetter: state => state.profile,
    },
    mutations: {
        getProfileMutation(state, profile){
            state.profile = profile
        },
    },
    actions: {
        getProfileAction({ commit }){
            Vue.http.get("/api/auth/profile/")
                .then((response) => {
                    commit("getProfileMutation", response.body)
                })
                .catch((error => {
                    console.log(error.statusText)
                }))
        },
    }

})
```

В котором по умолчанию profile = null
через getProfileAction идем в апи и берем там профиль

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import '@babel/polyfill'
import store from 'store/store'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import App from 'pages/App.vue'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import router from 'router/router'
import { abilitiesPlugin } from '@casl/vue'

Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin)
Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    render: a => a(App),
})
```

Компонент APP

```
export default {
        methods: {
            ...mapActions(['getHelpDeskTasksAction', 'getProfileAction']),
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapState(['profile'])
        },
        created(){
            //Go to api and get profile
            this.$store.dispatch('getProfileAction').then((profile) => {
                console.log(profile) //null
            })
            //Go to api and get help desk task
            this.$store.dispatch('getHelpDeskTasksAction')
            //Update CASL
            console.log(this.profile) //null                
        }
    }
```

Почему я в `console.log` получаю `null`
я понимаю что это потому что консоль выводится ранее чем получаем данные из апи
но как получить данные c api в Vuex, а потому уже вывести их в консоль

В template  я нормально получаю profile обновленный

Comment: А где вы в `getProfileAction` *возвращаете* промис?

Answer (score 1):

> this.$store.dispatch('getProfileAction').then((profile) => {
>                   console.log(profile) //null
>               })

Вы почему-то решили что dispatch('getProvileAction') вернет вам Promise ? Он вам воощбе ничего не должен возвратить (хотя я тут могу ошибаться ибо вы вызываете then и  не выдается ошибка). Данный action меняет состояние state.profile

Vue автоматом изменяет отрисовку при изменении реактивных свойств. Соответственно если у вас возвращается объект из api или массив, вы должны соответствующим образом поменять состояние profile.

Вот [тут](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) вы можете почитать более внимательно. Обратите на начальное состояние вашего profile

Если у вас не предполагается в дальнейшем обновлять данную  модель - вы можете попросту воспользоваться при присвоении значения Vue.set(state.profile, newKey, newResult)  при объекте либо state.profile.push(newResult) ежели получаете массив.